# How to prevent buttons from wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

How would this be done in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/08pjf5c7/

**This is the code I am trying to fix:** https://jsfiddle.net/e9gjs6hz/

Inside the jsfiddle code example when the width of the panel gets smaller, the buttons don't stay in place.

How is that fixed in the code?

How do I prevent wrapping of the buttons?

What would work in the code?

It's asking me to provide more in but that is all I am trying to do.

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  display: flex;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background: green;
  animation: fadeInButtons 3s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInButtons {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer.isOpen {
  /*display: flex;*/
  width: auto;
  /*align-content: stretch;*/
}

.fadingOut .isOpen {
  animation: fadingOut 1s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes fadingOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.bg1 .outer {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
}

/*body*/
.bg1 {
  animation: fadeInBody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

.thePlay {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
  fill: green;
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}


.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="play">
        <title>Play</title>
        <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
        <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
               M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add  `white-space: nowrap` and change your .container class like so

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}
```

And add a `<div class="container">` block around your existing HTML

```
<div class "container">
<div class="outer">
  <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="play">
        <title>Play</title>
        <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
        <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
               M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me that working in here? https://jsfiddle.net/e9gjs6hz/

Comment: @htmlcssjava321 Sure thing. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/gv6spfox/

Answer (score 0):

I clean up your code:

Your main problem:

- Do not use fixed height/width (90X90 in your code) for responsive cols layout (3 cols => use 33.33% or any relative unit).
- For the wrapper use `max-width` not `width` (Again to avoid overflow issues).

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="play">
        <title>Play</title>
        <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
        <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
               M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```